# git shows mysterious changes

Tags: git, diff, commit, line-endings

I'm facing this issue constantly when working in a team. Every time I push changes, there are some changes that weren't made by me, and I can't seem to understand what has changed. I attached an example screenshot from Fork.

You can see there are tiny character highlighted at the end of line 64.
The file has LF line ending format, and I don't think it is mixing it with CRLF.

The team uses different OS and IDE's

[image]

**Note:** the highlighted character is not a space. I can't post the text here as it get reformatted by SO.

Comment: “The team uses different OS and IDE's” That’s probably why. Windows and Unix and Mac all use different line endings.

Comment: Maybe https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

Comment: We are already using `* -text` in .gitattributes file

Comment: Try to compare contents of those two files in some hex editor – I'm pretty sure that there is some line ending related changes.

Answer (score 0):

I can be end of line spaces or new line characters.
For example, maybe they added (accidentally) spaces after the brackets and their editors don't automatically trim them, and yours might be configured to trim them, making them disappear, creating the changes.

You should really synchronize with your team to use the same editor settings (type of new lines characters, trimming end of lines and so on) to avoid situations like that.

Comment: Nope, we all agreed to use tabs, plus the one in the picture is not a space or tab, it is just hidden character

Comment: I did not talk about the type of indentation, but spaces at the end of the lines. However, yes making sure you all use the same indentations is also important.